# Sampling without Replacement...Hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose a box contains 500 white balls and 500 green balls. Five balls are taken at random without replacement. What is the approximate probability that 2 white balls and 3 green balls are taken?

I calculated using $$\frac{C(500,2) * C(500, 3)}{C(1000,5)}$$ and I get ~.313. Does this make sense? I feel like it's too high of a value.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yeap it's correct. Nothing wrong. Out of the 500 Green, you chose 3 (5C3) and out of the 500 white, you chose 2 (500C2). That is no. way of ways to select the given requirement. Dividing by the totally no. of ways to choose 5 balls out of 1000 (1000C5) would get you the probability.

Comment: The expression is correct. Since $500$ is a very big number in comparison with $5$, the probability is close to the "with replacemet" probability, which is $\binom{5}{2}(1/2)^5$.

Comment: Since population is 100 times sample size, I feel that by writing "approximate probability", they are suggesting that you use the binomial distribution. Of, course, your answer is right, in fact, more accurate.